# How does Firefox's "first-party isolation" feature function?

Tags: cookies, firefox

First-party isolation (`privacy.firstparty.isolate` in about:config, set to `false` by default) [originated from the Tor browser](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Tor_Uplift) and was recently added to Firefox. Unfortunately I haven't found enough official documentation and don't fully understand the functionality. Does this setting *fully* separate first-party cookies (third-party cookies can generally be safely disabled in web browsers, but additionally, how are they handled?) and related identifiable data (what data?).

Answer (score 10):

From a [cursory look](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1260931), they isolate the cookies (and other data) on silos based on the domain you navigated to.
So eg. a load to facebook.com when visiting www.stackexchange.com, would put facebook cookies inside a different silo than the facebook load when accessing twitter.com (however, the facebook loaded from meta.stackexchange.com would use the same silo as www.stackexchange.com)

> Does this setting fully separate first-party cookies (third-party cookies can generally be safely disabled, but additionally, how are they handled?)

This is not "separating first-party cookies", as much as making a more detailed origin based on where you initially navigated to.

> and related identifiable data (what data?).

cookies are just a part of the data a page could save. I'm pretty sure this would also apply to localStorage, maybe even partition the cache.